# AJAX / PHP error handling and global variable

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

this is my first time writing an ajax below is my structure

submitted.php

```
<?php $a = $_POST['a'];  // an input submitted from index.php ?>
<button>bind to jquery ajax</button>  // call ajax 
<span></span> // return ajax result here 

<script>
       $('button').on('click', function() {
        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
                  method: "POST",
                  url: "test.php",
                  data: { "key" : 'data'}
                })
                  .done(function( msg ) {
                    $('span').html(msg);
                });
    });
</script>
```

test.php

```
<?php echo $a; // will this work? ?>
```

ajax return blank... no error, my error_reporting is on.

Comment: First thing I noticed is you should have `$_POST['a']` not `$POST_['a']`.

Comment: typo... I have about 10 inputs that I need to pass to ajax... is there a way to do this? such as `echo $a` in `data:` ?

Answer (score 2):

No, there are a few things wrong with this:

- You are posting a key - value pair where the key is `key`, so you would need `$_POST['key']` in your php script;
- You should use `.preventDefault()` if you need to prevent an event like a form submit that is caused by your button. If that is the case, you need to get the `event` variable from your event handler: `$('button').on('click', function(event) {`.
  If there is no event to prevent, you can simply remove that line;
- If you do have a form (it seems so from your comment), you can easily send all key - value pairs using: `data: $('form').serialize()`.

Comment: .serialize() looks really promising, let me take a look at the doc. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

form.php

```
<button>bind to jquery ajax</button>  <!-- ajax trigger -->
<span></span> <!-- return ajax result here  -->

<script>

    // NOTE: added event into function argument
    $('button').on('click', function(event) {
         event.preventDefault();

         $.ajax({
             method: "POST",
             url: "test.php",
             data: { "key" : 'data'}
         })
         .done(function(msg) {
             $('span').html(msg);
         });
    });
</script>
```

process.php

```
<?php 

    echo (isset($_POST['key'])) ? $_POST['key'] : 'No data provided.';

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is the way to do it:

ubmitted.php

```
<button>bind to jquery ajax</button>  // call ajax 
<span></span> // return ajax result here 

<script>
       $('button').on('click', function() {
        // no need to prevent default here (there's no default)
        $.ajax({
                  method: "POST",
                  url: "test.php",
                  data: { "key" : 'data'}
                })
                  .done(function( msg ) {
                    $('span').html(msg);
                });
    });
</script>
```

test.php

```
<?php 
   if (isset($_POST['key'])
     echo $_POST['key'];
   else echo 'no data was sent.';
 ?>
```